# How to get HashMap (Object) out of Value in Haskell, Aeson?

Tags: parsing, haskell, aeson

I'm trying to get used to some haskell libraries by solving some online practice problems.

I have some code which outputs this

```
Object (fromList [("ABC", String "123")])
```

It may also be

```
Object (fromList [("123", String "ABC")])
Object (fromList [(String "123", String "ABC")])
Object (fromList [("123", "ABC")])
```

what I need to extract is `"123"`

using `.:` which has type `(.:) :: FromJSON a => Object -> Text -> Parser a`  to extract value given key raises this error

```
• Couldn't match type ‘Value’ with ‘HashMap Text Value’                                                         
  Expected type: Object
    Actual type: Value
```

My best guess is that I'm going to have to write a parser, but I have no idea how to go about doing that or what to look for.

Code that produced the error :

```
x <- (eitherDecode <$> simpleHttp url) :: IO (Either String DataSet)
  case x of
    Left er   -> print er
    Right an -> do
      let l = S.toList (data1 an)
      print $ l .: "ABC"
```

where DataSet is defined like this

```
newtype DataSet = DataSet {
                   data1  :: Object
                   } deriving (Show, Generic)
```

If I were to replace

```
print $ (Data.List.head l) .: "ABC"
```

with just

```
print $ (Data.List.head l)
```

I get

```
Object (fromList [("ABC", String "123")])
```

Comment: You haven't included the code that actually produces the error - could you please do so? It's possible, for example, that you have made a simple typo, that we cannot see here.

Comment: @AJFarmar added in the code that produced the error.

Comment: Great, thank you. I'm not sure if I've found the issue, but can I ask why you write `let l = L.toList (data1 an)` instead of `let l = data1 an`? That seems like it could be the issue here.

Comment: That's because `data1 an` outputs an `Object` type. `an` contains a lot of `Object (fromList [("ABC", "123")])`. Applying `toList` on it lets me convert it to a list and extract out each one at a time.

Comment: From what I understand `Object (fromList [("ABC", "123")])` has the type `Value` and just `fromList [("ABC", "123")]` has the type Object. So I think there should be a way to extract `Object` out of the `Value` type

Comment: That may be so, but still `l` is a list, and you're writing `l .: "ABC` which is not well-typed, so why are you writing that?

Comment: @AJFarmar Sorry that was my bad. I forgot to add `Data.List.head` in front of l. Fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One quick and dirty way of getting things out of `Value` type is to

encode `Value` as `ByteString`

encode has type `encode :: ToJSON a => a -> ByteString`

so here in your code

```
...
  case x of
    Left er   -> print er
    Right an -> do
      let l = S.toList (data1 an)
          x = (encode . snd) l  -- you can replace snd with fst if you want "ABC" instead of "123"
          y = decode x :: Maybe (HashMap String String)
          case y of
              Nothing -> print "got nothing"
              Just a -> print $ Data.HashMap.Strict.toList a
```

Which will output a list like this:

```
[("123")]
```

Now you can extract values with simple functions.

Hope that helps.

To know more about how you'd go about parsing JSON file better I would recommend giving https://artyom.me/aeson a good read.

Answer (score 2):

`Object` is one of several constructors of the [`Value` type](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.4.1.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html#t:Value)

```
Haskell Constructor | JSON Syntax
Object              | {"key": "value"}
String              | "hello"
Number              | 123
Array               | [1, 2, 3]
```

Note that in this case, the constructor `Object` is not a constructor of the type `Object`. [Note at end.]

The error comes from passing a `Value` to some function expecting an `Object`.  You will need to define what the program should do if it encounters any of the other cases.

Or since you have `data1 an :: Object`, you can lookup the key you want in that.  I'm not sure what the type of `S.toList` is, but you seem to be converting your `Object` to a `Value` and then passing it to `.:` which requires an Object.

Final note: `Object (fromList [("ABC", String "123")])` is a single Value with a single Object with one key-value pair. `fromList` is a way to create Objects from their parts (instead of by parsing JSON strings).

Comment: I'm still a beginner in haskell so this might be an odd question but wouldn't looking up key need the type to be `Object` instead of `Value` which is the result of the last `print` statement. Applying `data1` on `an` gives me a bunch of objects. Applying `toList` on it lets me choose which element I want. And from inside that element I need to extract the `"123"`. `toList data1 an` is equivalent to `[Value, Value, Value,....]`. Applying `head` means I ultimately get just `Value`.

Comment: It would help if you posted your entire program.  `.:` requires an Object.  According to the definition you gave of `data1 :: DataSet -> Object`, `data1 an :: Object`.  What are you seeing that suggests `data1 an` is "a bunch of objects"?  Whence are you importing `toList`?  There are several functions of that name.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ways you can unwrap the `Object` constructor from the `Value` data type.

You could create a function to unwrap:

```
unwrapValue :: Value -> Object
unwrapValue (Object x) = x
unwrapValue _ = error "No Object available"
```

Notice this function will return an error because there are possibilities where `Value` will not be an `Object`.

Also, don't get confused by `Object` being both a constructor of `Value` and a type in aeson!

You could unwrap inline as well but it is also not safe, meaning it can cause runtime errors. For example:

```
getNum :: Array -> Either String Scientific
getNum someArray = flip parseEither someArray $ \arr -> do
  let Just (Object obj) = arr !? 1 -- Unsafe unwrap Object constructor from Value (also unwraps Just constructor from Maybe)
  (Number num) <- obj .: "myNumber" -- Unsafe unwrap Number constructor from Value

  return num
```